# wcf client .exception "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https"

Tags: c#, wcf, service, client

I am creating client to WCF service. Service works across Sharepoint(I don't know, but maybe it's important)

config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
           <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="CommonServiceJSSoap_binding" >
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://blackwhite/_layouts/15/eos/commonservicejs.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonServiceJSSoap_binding"
            contract="CommonServices.CommonServiceJSSoap" name="CommonServiceJSSoap_endpint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Code:

```
 CommonServiceJSSoapClient client = new CommonServiceJSSoapClient();
        client.Open();
```

Open() `throw ArgumentException{"The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter name: via"}`

CommonServiceJSSoapClient  is autogenerated visual studio(VS add Service reference)

Anonymous access is denied.
if information is not enough , write me please in comment

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint requires authentication. It depends on how your Sharepoint admin has setup security.

Whenever we open a SharePoint site (without anonymous login enabled) the site will prompt with user credentials. As we are invoking through a web service the prompt dialog won't work. We need to pass the credentials using the property named Credentials.

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("appes", "password"); / // using System.Net;
```

Here are some code about some authentication forms:

```
protected void AuthenticateWindowsClassic(string domain, string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != null && userName.Length > 0)
            {
                api.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            }
            else
            {
                api.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }

            // Verify set credentials.
            System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = (System.Net.NetworkCredential) api.Credentials;
            Console.WriteLine(@"Credentials set to: {0}\{1}", cred.Domain, cred.UserName);
        }


protected bool AuthenticateFBAClaims(string userName, string password)
        {
            FBA.Authentication spAuthentication = new FBA.Authentication();
            spAuthentication.Url = farmURL + "_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx";

            spAuthentication.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            FBA.LoginResult loginResult = spAuthentication.Login(userName, password);
            authCookie = new Cookie();

            // Determines if login is successful.
            if (loginResult.ErrorCode == FBA.LoginErrorCode.NoError)
            {
                // Get the cookie collection from the authenticating Web service.
                CookieCollection cookies = spAuthentication.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(spAuthentication.Url));

                // Get the specific cookie that contains the security token.
                authCookie = cookies[loginResult.CookieName];

                // Initialize the cookie container of Excel Web Services.
                api.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                api.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
     }
```

Here are 2 step-by-step tutorials:

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-web-services/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff189907%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In binding security mode use TransportCredentialOnly instead of Transport